# Puedo representar números con una precisión decimal de más de 20 dígitos con python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matrices, numpy, python-3.7

Estoy realizando un programa de resolución de matrices con el método de Gauss para mi asignatura de álgebra lineal y el profesor nos aporta las soluciones con una precisión de 27 dígitos.

Estoy trabajando con matrices de numpy si sirve de ayuda.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Por el lado de `numpy` puedes consultar la [documentación](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.types.html), que podríamos resumir así:

- Puedes usar alguno de los tipos más clásicos `np.double`, `np.float`, etc. con el cual llegas a una precisión de 15 decimales
- Puedes, dependiendo del sistema operativo y la herramienta de compilación con la que se generó la biblioteca `numpy`, acceder al `np.longdouble` o `np.float128` con el cual puedes llegar a los 18 decimales

Hay una rutina muy útil `np.finfo()`, para obtener información de los distintos tipos de datos que maneja este paquete, los resultados dependen, como te decía antes del SO y el compilador:

```
import numpy as np

print(np.finfo(np.double))
print(np.finfo(np.float))
print(np.finfo(np.longdouble))

Machine parameters for float64
---------------------------------------------------------------
precision =  15   resolution = 1.0000000000000001e-15
machep =    -52   eps =        2.2204460492503131e-16
negep =     -53   epsneg =     1.1102230246251565e-16
minexp =  -1022   tiny =       2.2250738585072014e-308
maxexp =   1024   max =        1.7976931348623157e+308
nexp =       11   min =        -max
---------------------------------------------------------------

Machine parameters for float64
---------------------------------------------------------------
precision =  15   resolution = 1.0000000000000001e-15
machep =    -52   eps =        2.2204460492503131e-16
negep =     -53   epsneg =     1.1102230246251565e-16
minexp =  -1022   tiny =       2.2250738585072014e-308
maxexp =   1024   max =        1.7976931348623157e+308
nexp =       11   min =        -max
---------------------------------------------------------------

Machine parameters for float128
---------------------------------------------------------------
precision =  18   resolution = 1e-18
machep =    -63   eps =        1.084202172485504434e-19
negep =     -64   epsneg =     5.42101086242752217e-20
minexp = -16382   tiny =       3.3621031431120935063e-4932
maxexp =  16384   max =        1.189731495357231765e+4932
nexp =       15   min =        -max
---------------------------------------------------------------
```

Finalmente, `numpy` no trabaja con precisiones mayores a las indicadas, podrías integrar, como ya te han comentado, los objetos de la clase `Decimal` de python, pero tienes que entender, que al no ser datos nativos, `numpy` los trata como objetos y hay una penalidad enorme de performance con cualquier operación que hagas.

Otra posibilidad es que investigues por el lado de las librerías que ofrecen una precisión arbitraria, como ser:

- [`mpmath`](http://mpmath.org/)
- [`sympy`](https://www.sympy.org/en/index.html)

Answer (score 4):

Con la libreria [decimal](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/decimal.html) de python

Puedes usar números Decimales, importando Decimal y con getcontext limitar la precision con que quieres el número, aqui te dejo un ejemplo

```
from decimal import Decimal, getcontext
getcontext().prec = 27
answer = Decimal(1) / Decimal(12)
print (answer)
```

Comment: El link corresponde a una versión sin soporte, 2.7.x y distinta a la que el usuario pide en las etiquetas. La documentación con la versión actual sería: [decimal](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/decimal.html). Puedes editar la respuesta y actualizar el enlace.

Comment: Actualizado, gracias.